# Using the available version of Excel for C# app development

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2017, excel-interop

Is there an elegant/straightforward way to make use of Microsoft Excel in a C# app, without being tied down to a specific version of Microsoft Excel?

Background...

I have in the past written scripts using vbscript which use Microsoft Excel (if installed) to automate the process of generating excel spreadsheets.  `set xl = createObject("Excel.Application")`

The scripts work seamlessly regardless of which excel version is installed *in my experience/scenario* (I have Office 365 with Excel 2016 installed on my development machine,  and my scripts run on a Microsoft Windows 2008 R2 server running a standalone copy of Excel 2010)

I wish to step things up a bit and start developing C# apps (winforms or console) that do the same job.  I have developed a test app which can use the version of excel installed on my development machine.  I need the app to be able to run on the Windows Server 2008 R2 server running Excel 2010.

`Project->Add Reference`

`COM`

`"Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library"`

Then add the using statement... `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Then some basic winforms test code...

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SimpleExcelTest();
    }

    void SimpleExcelTest() {

        Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];

        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Testing";
        wb.SaveAs("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx");
        wb.Close();
    }
```

Which works fine.

But this references the specific version of Excel running on my machine.  This won't run on the target machine.  The application crashes with the following error...

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
>
> Problem Signature 01:   AutomatedReportGenerator.exe
>
> Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
>
> Problem Signature 03:   59552369
>
> Problem Signature 04:   AutomatedReportGenerator
>
> Problem Signature 05:   1.0.0.0
>
> Problem Signature 06:   59552369
>
> Problem Signature 07:   2
>
> Problem Signature 08:   9c
>
> Problem Signature 09:   PSZQOADHX1U5ZAHBHOHGHLDGIY4QIXHX
>
> OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
>
> Locale ID:  2057
>
> Additional Information 1:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Additional Information 3:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

*Edit*:I will put in a try catch to see if I can catch a more useful error message, and also try the library that two answers have suggested then accept the earliest answer.  Later today.

Is there an alternative/better way to use Excel in a C# App to generate spreadsheets, regardless of which version of excel is installed (as long as its recent enough to be compatible with the code)

Perhaps a C# equivalent of vbscript's `set xl = createObject("Excel.Application")`

Comment: Is the Excel interop assembly property "Embed Interop Types" set to True?

Comment: @PaulF Yes it is.

Comment: I tried searching for Problem Signature 09 as it was quite unique & came up with several results including this - I don't know if it will help : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/i-am-trying-to-install-a-program-on-my-windows-7/917f70b9-2915-4662-a7dc-ac997312501b

Comment: If using .xlsx only then consider SpreadSheetLight free un-restricted version http://spreadsheetlight.com/ and make sure to download the help file.

Comment: Office automation is bit shaky ! Office Open Xml (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-content/tree/master/en-us/OpenXMLCon) and wrappers around it and more robust ways to generate Excel sheets. You can take a look at these.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking into not using Excel Interop and using a library that can read/write the format?  EPPlus is one I've used countless times and it has a lot of functionality: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus

Answer (score 2):

Try using EPPLus, it's super easy to use and comes up with many useful features like it takes care of special characters in cells, etc. You can download EPPlus from http://epplus.codeplex.com/ . Nuget page of EPPlus is https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus

I would not recommend using Microsoft Excel Interop because of it's complexities.

One code sample is

```
 using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(fileName)))
            {
               ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[excelSheetName];

                ws.Cells["A" + rowCnt].Value = firstName;
                ws.Cells["B" + rowCnt].Value = lastName;
                ws.Cells["C" + rowCnt].Value = occupation;

                pck.Save();

            }
```

Thanks.